# PySpark: How to read back a Bucketed table written to S3?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to work with bucketing in PySpark, using these general examples:
https://gist.github.com/luminousmen/8dffa01a02bb58946b1299a621e44897

https://towardsdatascience.com/best-practices-for-bucketing-in-spark-sql-ea9f23f7dd53

I write the bucketed table to S3 like so:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("bucketing test").enableHiveSupport().config(
    "spark.sql.sources.bucketing.enabled", "true").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)

# Create the DF
df = spark.range(1, 16000, 1, 16).select(
    F.col("id").alias("key"), F.rand(12).alias("value")
)
# Write the DF to disk
df.write.bucketBy(8, "key").sortBy("value").saveAsTable(
    "bucketed_table", format="parquet", mode="overwrite", path="s3a://my/s3/path"
)
```

Then, I try to read it back and test the bucketed join.

```
df_bucketed = spark.sql("""
       CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bucketed_table (
           key int,
           value float
       ) STORED AS PARQUET
       CLUSTERED BY (key) SORTED BY (value) INTO 8 BUCKETS
       LOCATION 's3a://my/s3/path'
    """
)
# Print the extended describe and confirm bucketing works
logging.info("Extended Describe: %s" % spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED bucketed_table")._jdf.showString(100, 40, False))
logging.info("Bucketed table columns: %s" % df_bucketed.columns)
```

Which leads to the output:

[image: Program output]

Why is the resulting DF read with no columns? Is there a better way to read a bucketed DF in PySpark from S3?

Note that spark.table("") doesn't work for me, because I need to specify an S3 path (and I don't know how to do that in the table() call).

Comment: I don't understand why you can't call spark.table(). What happens when you call spark.table("bucketed_table") ? If your metastore is set up correctly, it should work and spark should give you back a DataFrame that represents the saved data.

Comment: That would work, but spark.table() by default reads from the "/tmp" directory (I get an error to that effect saying "Table or view not found". How can I specify the path to the S3 bucket in the .table() call?

Answer (score 0):

`df_bucketed = spark.sql("CREATE TABLE ...")` will give you this empty DataFrame result, as you are seeing. That is because a create statement returns an empty DataFrame on success. That result also happens to have some of the created table's metadata, which is confusing.

The fix is very simple, use `spark.table("bucketed_table")`, which will read the bucketed table. If you're having an issue with that, you can also use `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM bucketed_table")`, which basically the same as the table load, since Spark is smart about which columns will actually be used.